# Swift - accessing structs

Tags: struct, enums, swift

If I have a struct defined like this:

```
struct Cat {
    static let Siamese = "Siamese"
    static let Tabby = "Tabby"
    static let Fluffy = "Fluffy"

    static func cat () -> [String] {
        return [Siamese, Tabby, Fluffy]
    }
}
```

Why can't I access it like this?

```
var cat:Cat = Cat.Siamese //"NSString" is not a subtype of Cat
```

Comment: What is the semantics of Cat.cat()?  It surely doesn't read properly.  One of the important programming aspects is to avoid differences between the code/model and the real world.  Suggest `class CatBreed { let name ... }` and `class Cat { let breed : CatBreed ... }`.  Your code is 'fighting' with itself (in your use of `static let ...` and the `static func cat()`).

Comment: you should call like this                                           var cat:String = Cat.Siamese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign a String to a variable defined as a `Cat`. That is why you are getting an error.

All of your static members in your `Cat` struct are strings, not `Cat`s.

Also, your struct doesn't have any actual members. I think you are intending to have a name property:

```
struct Cat {
    let name: String

    static let Siamese = Cat(name: "Siamese")
    static let Tabby = Cat(name: "Tabby")
    static let Fluffy = Cat(name: "Fluffy")
}

var cat : Cat = Cat.Siamese
```

You may be better served with an enum:

```
enum Cat : String {
    case Siamese = "Siamese"
    case Tabby = "Tabby"
    case Fluffy = "Fluffy"
}

var cat: Cat = .Tabby
println(cat.toRaw()) // "Tabby"
```